# issues with deploying rails servers to multiple hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soa

I've heard often that deploying a traditional monolithic Rails app (i.e. no internal Web API, no message queue, no Redis/memcached server) to multiple servers can produce a bunch of bugs that are very hard to debug but I'm having a hard time coming up with some concrete examples despite a few hours of googling

Some obvious issues that I can think of are:

Observers - likely will not work properly as the observation is only propagated on one server and not all of them (assuming there is no Message Queue)

Sessions - would probably need to store these in the database which would need it's own host

Caches - any sweepers would have issues propagating invalidations between servers.

Anyone else care to contribute?  I'd really appreciate any articles others may have come across or just general wisdom :)

Answer (score 0):

Observers are just code callbacks. 
They run on each process, on each server.

Sessions have defaulted to the cookie store for the last few years. 
So multiple servers are no problem. 
If you don't have enough space in your cookie then I suggest you may be doing something wrong.

Cache invalidation is indeed a problem. 
But it always is. 
One solution is to break your cache out into a standalone service. 
 Sites like Facebook have giant farms of memcache

I think scaling and clustering is always a hard problem. 
But this seems to be an old argument against rails. 
If anything the last few years have seen rails shine in this respect. 
With ec2, nosql, and server automation becoming quite a norm in the community.

Comment: Yeah I totally believe Rails can scale up no problem, I'm just working with a legacy Rails 2.3 app right now and trying to convince other people of taking baby steps to scaling :)

Comment: Observers make sense - the problem will arise when you expect an observation to occur on each server - caching is a good example of this but thats another issue entirely.

Session I don't totally follow on.  I suppose you're saying all the session data is stored entirely in the cookie - which is a great reason to turn to DB store on it's own. I guess it would break if you are using something like FileStore.

Comment: if you use the cookie store then there is no tie between server and browser. if your data is small enough, then why wouldn't you use it.

Comment: haha i wish i could guarantee that, but i have a feeling the cookies store a lot more information than they should =/ good old SOS projects...

Comment: I had a project that stored a lot of state, but I realised it was actually a persistent object. So I created a GameState model, and just stored `session[:gate_state_id] = @game_state.id`. It's equivalent to a database session, but more flexible and explicit.